# Increase max upload file size in WordPress Multisite network?

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ini

I'm trying to increase the max file size for a WordPress multisite install (currently 1MB). I've tried a number of things to no avail. The things I've tried:

Adding these to my hosts php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 300M
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

Adding these to the functions.php file in the theme:

```
@ini_set('upload_max_size' , '32M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '32M');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
```

Adding these to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

I even tried checking the wp-includes/default-constants.php.

Interestingly, I have another WordPress install (not multisite) on the same server that seems to work perfectly (max upload there is 32MB). Any ideas what to try next?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out. In all my infinite wisdom, I completely missed the "Max upload file size" setting in Network Admin > Settings > Network Settings. It's right near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Ramie It's in the Network Admin (My Sites > Network Admin) then go to Settings > Network Settings. It's near the bottom under Upload Settings, called Max upload file size.

Comment: can't see it, does it appear in the self-hosted wordpress instance ?

Comment: Yup. It's there for me. Are you sure you're in the network admin, not just the site admin?

Comment: i am on site admin. haven't been to the network admin before. anyways i fixed the problem by uploading a .user.ini file

Comment: I've tried all above steps and also tried increasing value in Network admin. Still I'm getting 2MB on media upload screen

Answer (score 3):

Phil is correct: Network Admin (My Sites > Network Admin) then go to Settings > Network Settings. It's near the bottom under Upload Settings, called Max upload file size.

However, also note you have to go with a flat 1000kb or 2000kb etc.

I put 1500kb in there and it still limited me to 1 MB but when I increased it to 2000kb it allowed up to 2 MB

Answer (score 3):

@Allpnay posted the solution, just paste on functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'PBP_increase_upload' );
function PBP_increase_upload( $bytes )
{
  return 1048576; // 1 megabyte
}
```

---

In my case want 8mb so change for
return 8000000; // 8 megabyte

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i use this filter for my Multisite and this work great

```
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'PBP_increase_upload' );
function PBP_increase_upload( $bytes )
{
return 1048576; // 1 megabyte
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called .user.ini in your Wordpress root folder and add the following to it:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

This fixed it for me after all else failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `php.ini` file with

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
file_uploads = On
```

and save it in the `wp-admin/` folder :)

If this doesn't work, try adding the following to `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '32M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '32M');
```

Comment: Still no luck. Max upload size is still 1MB.

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you try adding those lines in wp-config.php. Also, do you have any `php.ini` files in your wordpress folders / ini_set's somewhere else?

Comment: Sadly, still nothing. I don't have any php.ini files anywhere in the WordPress install.

Comment: Create php.ini inside wp-admin folder and make the changes . 
It will work for sure.

Comment: i tried this solutions and none of them worked for me. Still shows 2MB upload limit.

Comment: If none of the above work, then you will need to increase it in the main php.ini config. You can make a php file and write `phpinfo();` in it, then access that file and you should see all the config information. What you're looking for is under "Loaded Configuration File", you will need to edit that file.

If that file also has a maximum upload file size increase, but you don't see it, then you need to edit your webserver config, aka nginx config, or apache config or whatever webserver you have.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for a programmatic solution, this is what we are doing in [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-install-wordpress-packages.txt) on brand new installations to change this setting value:

```
ss_mysql --execute="UPDATE ${DB_NAME}.${DB_PREFIX}sitemeta SET option_value='16000' WHERE option_name='fileupload_maxk'";
```

Note that adjusting `php.ini` settings will have no effect because WordPress Multisite has it's own special setting for this in the database.